# Calculating difference between two matrices to a scalar

Tags: matrices, determinant

I want to calculate the difference between two n x n matrices to a scaler. That measure should give the idea about the physical location of each values too. For example if I name some operation with '`~`'

```
A = 1 0    B = 2 0   C = 0 0   D = 0 0
    0 0        0 0       1 0       2 0
```

If '~' is to compare each pixel which is A[i, j] with B[i, j] and to get the summation of them, it gives `B ~ A = D ~ C = 1`

But since the measure should give an idea about the locations `B ~ A` and `D ~ C` cannot be equal because in A,B the change is in [0,0] and in C,D the change is in [1,0]

So what are the measures/ ways that I can calculate the difference of two matrices to a scaler reflecting their physical locations?

Comment: I don't think a scalar can give you the information of both the location and the difference of the numbers. And I didn't quite understand your example. Shouldn't B~A=D~C=3?

Comment: @KittyL I just calculated the error without squaring just for simplicity. Squaring makes sense too :)

Answer (score 1):

For $A\sim B$ you could calculate a new matrix $N_{ij} = \left\{\begin{array}{l}1 \text{ if } A_{ij}\ne B_{ij}\\0 \text{ if } A_{ij}= B_{ij}\end{array}\right.$, then define $A \sim B = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n N_{ij}2^{in+j}$.  Then $\sim$ is basically a large binary number, each non-zero bit of which indicates a difference between $A$ and $B$ at a particular location.

Comment: I think this maps a dataset into a scalar. This gives the same answer either this is a matrix of size n x n or a vector of size n^2.

Comment: @user3218743: That's correct.

Comment: Good strategy....

Comment: @Frentos Thanks. Will wait for few days for more answers and will accept this if nothing better found :)